# Extracting Namespaces from XML in Python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have something similar to the following XML document, called `sample.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns:test='www.test.com' xmlns:test2='www.test2.com'>
    <test:items>
        <test2:item>Some information</test2:item>
    </test:items>
</package>
```

I would like to use Python (2.7) to extract a dictionary of the namespaces as below:

```py
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
>>> namespaces = {} # This is the dictionary I want to populate
```

Required output of code:

```py
>>> namespaces 
{'test':'www.test.com', 'test2':'www.test2.com'}
```

I have read the documentation for `ElementTree` but haven't got anywhere yet. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you swap the standard library's `xml` for the near-identical but more powerful [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), then it's as simple as

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
namespaces = tree.nsmap
```